# Scrolling on WebView keeps generating glUtilsParamsSize error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I am implementing a list view with a WebView as an element. However, when I scroll to the WebView the system kept generating this error:

```
E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x65687420 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
```

Here is what I do in getView() to return the WebView:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
...
if (position == 5) {
    WebView contentWebView = (WebView) convertView;

    if (contentWebView == null || !(convertView instanceof WebView)) {
       contentWebView = new WebView(parent.getContext());
       // htmlString is a String in HTML format.
       contentWebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");
       contentWebView.setPadding(ARTICLE_VIEW_TEXT_PADDING, 0, ARTICLE_VIEW_TEXT_PADDING, 0);
       AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       contentWebView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

  return contentWebView;
}
}
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I loaded a site which contains a Image slider. The logcat produces the same error code when the image in slider is changes the images. I assumed that it might because of the webpage computes the size of the screen of my device. I just gussed because its from gl, Im not sure..

Its better to switch to activity instead of fragment if you are using fragment. Because I found that this error log is not generated when I used activity. I'm not sure, but it may be a clue for you. Please let me know after you check.